# Split list with RegEx when the only delimiters are ":" and space

Tags: php, regex

I have a list (string) of data that I would like to split into variables using regular expression:

> Company Name: Some Company Telephone: (123) 456-7890 Email: name@domain.com

I would like to get it to:

> $company = 'Some Company', $phone = '(123) 456-7890', $email ='name@domain.com'

Where I am running into problems is the only delimiter is ':' and spaces. I have not started formulating a regex pattern yet. I tried using explode but that was adding the next item onto the last. ie;

```
$pieces = explode(":", $list);
$pieces[0]  // Company Name
$pieces[1] // Some Company Telephone
...
```

Comment: Aren't `Company Name: ` and `Email: ` and `Telephone: ` also "delimiters"?

Comment: I'm with @PeeHaa and also show the code you have so far, I suspect the problem is acutally something different than your delimiters, e.g. not following those correctly to split up.

Comment: The code is a plaintext string from an HTML page. Also, see my edit to the original post.

Comment: Looks like `sprintf` is more useful here than explode ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to split the line with regular expression:

```
$str = "Company Name: Some Company Telephone: (123) 456-7890 " .
    "Email: name@domain.com";

list(, $company, $telephone, $email) =
    preg_split("/\s*(?:Company Name|Telephone|Email):\s*/", $str);
```

Comment: You should respect the order of elements in the original string. Your regex does not reflect that (yet).

Comment: @hakre Here the original string and elements of `list` match. Hence, this could work as a basic parser.